# Multi bar chat with Flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Any sample code for chart with multiple bars using flot ??[image]

similar to [this example](http://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=159) . The given patched files are not working for me. Anywhere I can download the latest files for multi bar graph.

**Update**

I am sure Flot is a very good library but plugins/add-ons are not available easily and the examples given on the website are very basic, so I decided to use [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/) instead

Answer (score 9):

**Updated Info:** Andión's answer makes reference to this library. [Bars-side-by-side](http://en.benjaminbuffet.com/labs/flot/)

You can download the code here: 
http://www.benjaminbuffet.com/public/js/jquery.flot.orderBars.js

The result is :
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X76o.png]

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried the [orderBars](http://en.benjaminbuffet.com/labs/flot/) plugin?
[image: Flot orderBars plugin]

You can download the code [here](http://click-charts-enhanced.googlecode.com/svn-history/r61/trunk/click-charts-enhanced-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/flot/jquery.flot.orderBars.js)

Comment: @MagnusLindhe http://click-charts-enhanced.googlecode.com/svn-history/r61/trunk/click-charts-enhanced-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/flot/jquery.flot.orderBars.js

Comment: I updated the outdated links as noted by @AbdullahDiaa and pmking

Answer (score 1):

You have to treat each bar as its own data series, so if you see 11 bars you need to create 11 data series.

Here's sample code for 2 bars.

```
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

var d1 =[0, 2];
var d2 =[1,3];

var startData = [
    {   //first series
        label:"d1",
        data: [d1],
        bars:{
            show: true,
            fill: true,
            fillColor: "red"
        }
    },
    {   //second series
        label:"d2",
        data: [d2],
        bars:{
            show: true,
            fill: true,
            fillColor: "blue"
        }
    }
];

var option={
        series: {
                bars:{
                        show: true,
                        fill: true
                }
        },
        grid: {
                hoverable: true,
                clickable: true
        },
        yaxis: { ticks: 5 }
    };

$.plot($("#placeholder"),startData,option  );
```

});

Comment: this does not work for me, i'm using flot 0.6, copy pasted this code and the bars just end up rendering over each other

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the values that you're passing in on the X-axis (of your bar series).

You don't need a different series for each bar, that would be.... excessive.

What you do need is a different series for each *colour* of bar (or more accurately, each different set of rendering settings that you'd like to have in your chart).

I realize you've moved on, but if you want to post the code that was giving you issues, it might help other people. The examples on the flot site are pretty straight-forward, so it may have just been something simple (like your X-axis value if they weren't defined) that was tripping you up.

I'm using flot in a production system to render three different bar series (red, yellow and green bars) so it sounds like a very similar solution what you're trying to do.

Comment: I would be curious to see what you are using it for Peter.